# Comment savoir s'il faut utiliser "à + pronom tonique" ou "le pronom COI"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'expliquer pourquoi dit on:

> Je fais appel **à lui**.

et non :

> *Je **lui** fais appel.

Également, pourquoi :

> Je **lui** passe un coup de fil.

et non :

> *Je passe un coup de fil **à lui**.

Comment savoir s'il faut utiliser la forme "à + pronom tonique" ou  seulement "le pronom COI" ?

Comment: J'ai un pb avec le titre de la question. Mais peut-être n'est-ce que moi. Pour moi, *lui*, comme qu'il soit utilisé c'est à dire ici dans les deux cas de figure reste un pronom tonique. Dans le cas *à lui* il est juste disjoint. (du verbe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il existe deux imprécisions dans votre façon de comprendre ce sujet.

-1 Il ne peut pas y avoir d'opposition entre COI et « pronom tonique »; les deux possibilités se trouvent, et la fonction grammaticale doit être la même.
-2 L'usage qui importe est applicable au cas d'autres compléments que le COI, c'est à dire à certains compléments circonstanciels. *ex : Elle leur a donné une perle., À eux elle a donné une perle.*; « leur » et « eux » sont tous les deux un complément circonstanciel d'attribution.
Le [complément indirect](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4277) est habituellement placé à droite du verbe, sauf s’il s’agit d’un pronom personnel conjoint (lui, leur, y, en) ou d’un pronom relatif (dont, duquel, auquel…).

**1/** Si le verbe est pronominal alors **à** est utilisé.

> C'est la justice qui tranchera ; ils s'en remettent elle.(s'en remettre à qqc ou à qqu)       
>   Adressez-vous à lui, il doit avoir cette pièce.
>   Ils s'adressent à eux en hiver.(s'adresser à qqu) 
>   Ils s'en sont pris à elle. (s'en prendre à qqu) 
>   Nous nous référons à eux. (se référer à qqu)
>   Les enfants se sont joints à elles.

**2/** Autrement, dans certain cas (habituellement), le pronom est utilisé avant le verbe (sans « à »).

> Je lui fais signe. (faire signe à qqu)                      
>  
>   Ils lui portent querelle. (porter querelle à qqu)             
>   L'institutrice leur apprend le calcul. (apprendre qqc à qqu)  
>   Le crédit de cette révélation lui revient. (revenir à qqu)    
>   Le rapport leur a été soumis.                                 
>   Je lui demande la solution.                                   
>   Je ne lui dis rien.                                           
>   Lorsqu'il y a de la nourriture en plus il la leur donne.      
>   Cela leur arrive.                                             
>   Les gens leur téléphone.
>   La responsabilité leur échoua.
>   Ces terres leur reviennent de droit.

**3/** Dans d'autres cas, apparemment bien plus rares, le pronom avant le verbe n'est pas utilisé et c'est la préposition « à » et le pronom après le verbe qui sont utilisés.

> Je fais appel à lui.
>   Je retourne à lui. (Retourner à Dieu. [Dans la lang. des croyants] Mourir.)
>   Elle est revenue à lui, décidée de ne plus le quitter. (revenir à qqc, à qqu)
>   L'enfant couru à elle.

**4/** Lorsque l'on veut marquer une opposition et que normalement le cas « **1/** » est applicable, « à » est utilisé après le verbe.

> Je fais signe à elle, pas à lui, il ne répondrais pas.                                   
>   L'institutrice apprend le calcul seulement à eux; aux autres elle ne donne aucune leçon de calcul. 
>   Lorsqu'il y a de la nourriture en plus il la donne à eux, pas aux animaux.               
>   Lorsqu'il y a de la nourriture en plus il ne la donne pas aux animaux mais à eux.
>   Je rapporte les nouvelles à elle; à lui, je ne parle que de chasse.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que vous voulez dire par : "La prononciation n'est pas un critère dans cette question de grammaire ; la prononciation a rarement une incidence sur la grammaire" ? Qui parle de la prononciation ?

Comment: En résumé, on va utiliser "à"  avec le verbe pronominal et si on veut marquer une opposition, mais pour mes deux phrases il n'y a pas de règle ?

Comment: Oui, c'est ce que je crois, sauf que je dirais plutôt que ce sont des exceptions au lieu de parler d'un manque de règle, la règle étant ce que vous résumez.